# Inherit while using base template identifiers

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have two templates A and B both with the same template types. Always, A inherits from B, but it always chooses the same template for B as A itself uses.

This is fine in and of itself, but this requires me to write the template type twice. Is it possible to somehow typedef the type in A and refer to the generic typedef name when inheriting from the subclass?

Below is some example code that does not compile but should give a clear idea of what I want to do:

```
// #1
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    typename T type;
    // class details here
};

// #2
template <typename T>
struct B
{
    // class details here
};

// #3
template <>
struct A<int>
    : B<type> // Compiler complains here (type not defined)
    //: B<A::type> // Compiler complains here (type not defined)
    // I could write ": B<int>" instead, but this is repitition I want to avoid
{
    // class specialization details here
};
```

I'm open for alternative solutions. The reason this is important to me is that I have a large laundry list of code like that of #3 and I want to reduce duplication (to avoid bugs).

Comment: A<int> is not a type A, and thus A<int>::typeA is not defined. What you should do is A<int> : B<int> if you want the functionality you are asking for, but this is more likely a XY Problem?

Comment: Or 'template <> struct A<int>: B<A<int>::typeA>...' but this seam useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different specializations of the same template are completely unrelated types<sup>*</sup>, so you cannot use `A<>::type` from the base template inside the specialization `A<int>`. Even if you define `type` inside the `A<int>` specialization, it won't be available until the class is defined, which happens *after* the list of inheritance.

You could and you **should** use `: B<int>` there. It is no more repetition than `B<type>`, and makes it explicit that `A<int>` inherits from `B<int>`, something that is not immediately visible if you go through indirections.

Another thing that kind of bugs me from your design is that `A<>` (the generic one) does not have any relationship with `B<>`, but `A<int>` inherits from `B<int>`. While the language allows for completely unrelated behavior in specializations, that might be surprising to other programmers, when they can pass objects of `A<T>` to functions taking `B<T>` for some `T`, but not for others...

What is the actual problem that you want to get solved?

---

<sup>*</sup> The implication of this is that an *specialization* does not provide *special* behavior (i.e. only the bits that differ from the base) but *all* the behavior of that type. If you only mean to override part of the behavior you should consider other alternatives, like refactoring `A<T>` (generic) into a base so that `A<int>` (or other specializations) can borrow the implementation. Or if the changes in behavior are small you might be able to just specialize some of the member functions...

Comment: I suppose my small examples were a little abstract and a little wrong. A always derives from some B1, B2, ..., BN, so the behavior cannot be lifted directly into A. The real case scenario is mapping of constants (enums) to types that deal with that constant. Example: `Mapping<INT /*some integer value like 1*/>::function_type` would be the same as something like `void(*)(int)`. Inheriting some B will add invariants. All A's will inherit from some B, but the B is not fixed. An example is to configure some offset mechanism based on the constant value.

Comment: @ThomasEding: Just inherit from `B<int>` if you need that. You do understand why `::type` is not available there, right?

Comment: Yeah, marking this as the answer. I knew that my code didn't work and was wondering if some analogous thing *could* work. But it sounds like there is no (good) solution other than doing it the vanilla way.